# JEST - SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

Tags: typescript, next.js, jestjs, monorepo

I have a monorepo with 3 packages, namely:

- `web-app`: A NextJS 12 project in Typescript
- `web-core`: A redux-toolkit project used in `web-app`
- `web-ui`: A storybook project with components which are being used in `web-app`

The `web-ui` and `web-core` are in the `package.json` of `web-app`. Hence, `web-app` is dependent on `web-ui` and `web-core`. I'm trying to add testing in the `web-app` and I've done that by following [this guide](https://nextjs.org/docs/testing#setting-up-jest-with-the-rust-compiler).

I've added the following packages to `web-app` as `devDependencies`:

```
- jest
- ts-jest
- jest-environment-jsdom
- @testing-library/react
- @testing-library/jest-dom
- @types/testing-library__jest-dom
```

I've made my `jest.config.js` as follows:

```
const nextJest = require("next/jest");
const { pathsToModuleNameMapper } = require("ts-jest");
const { compilerOptions } = require("./tsconfig.json");

const createJestConfig = nextJest({ dir: "./" });

const customJestConfig = {
  clearMocks: true,
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["./jest.setup.ts"],
  moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths, {
    prefix: "src",
  }),
  verbose: true,
  collectCoverage: true,
  moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "tsx", "js"],
  modulePathIgnorePatterns: ["./__tests__/test-utils.tsx"],
  coveragePathIgnorePatterns: ["./__tests__/test-utils.tsx"],
  moduleDirectories: ["node_modules", "<rootDir>"],
  transformIgnorePatterns: ["../web-core"],
  testEnvironment: "jest-environment-jsdom",
};

module.exports = createJestConfig(customJestConfig);
```

My `jest.setup.ts` as follows:

```
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
```

I have my `test-utils.tsx` as follows:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";

// Add in any providers here if necessary:
const Providers: React.VFC<{ children: React.ReactElement }> = ({
  children,
}) => {
  return children;
};

const customRender = (ui: React.ReactElement, options = {}) =>
  render(ui, { wrapper: Providers, ...options });

export * from "@testing-library/react";

export { customRender as render };
```

And my `index.test.tsx` as follows:

```
import { render, screen } from "./test-utils";
import HomePage from "@user/home/HomePage";

describe("HomePage", () => {
  it("renders a heading", () => {
    const textToFind = "Some Text";

    render(<HomePage />);
    const heading = screen.getByText(textToFind);

    expect(heading).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

I run my tests using this script:

```
"test": "jest --config ./jest.config.js",
```

When I run the test script, it gives me an error in the `index.ts` of the `web-core` as something is being imported from there to `web-app`. It stops at the first line of `index.ts` with this error:

```
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){export * from "./auth";
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

I have the `index.ts` inside my `web-core` like this:

```
export * from "./auth";
export * from "./coach-mark";
export * from "./common/models";
export * from "./common/utils";
export * from "./crm";
export * from "./employee-access";
export * from "./example/todo-plain/hooks";
export * from "./example/todo-plain/selectors";
export * from "./example/todo-rtk-query/hooks";
export * from "./inventory/bulk-edit";
export * from "./inventory/history";
....
```

This is in `auth/index.ts`:

```
export * from "./otp";
export * from "./registration";
```

Inside both of `otp` and `registration` folders, there is a `hooks.ts` and `index.ts` file.

Inside `hooks.ts`:
`createApi` from `redux-toolkit` is being used to create some api calls. I'm exporting those api calls and the `createApi` like this:

```
const OtpApi = createApi({ ... });

export cosnt { ... } = OtpApi;

export default OtpApi;
```

Everything inside `index.ts` is exported like this:

```
export * from "./hooks";
```

Visual folder representation in `web-core`:

[image: folder-representation]

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Hi @Hasnain Ali! Great work on providing the details! I think it depends what kind of tests are you trying to write. Are there unit tests? if so, you want to mock the dependencies of other modules even if they are yours. If you want to test the entire thing, look at your jest config. it contains a `moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths, {
    prefix: "src",
  }),` line that tells jest how to find files. if you need access to all modules and not all of them are inside the src folder, you might need a more complicated rule here

Comment: @Thatkookooguy I want to do unit tests. I want to test out each page and some utility functions inside `web-app`. How should I proceed?